# Error: Getter not found: 'Firebase'. await Firebase.initializeApp();

Tags: dart

[Why I am getting error for that Firebase keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAJ8I.png)

Comment: This is the error message I am getting

lib/main.dart:6:9: Error: Getter not found: 'Firebase'.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
             ^^^^^^^^
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

Try to import firebase

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
```

Comment: It is showing error for firebase keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import firebase.
Try adding this to the beginning of your code,

```dart
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
```

This library contains the keyword `Firebase`.

If it shows an error in this line, open root/pubspec.yaml and add this code after dependencies.

```yaml
dependencies:
  # ...
  firebase_core: ^0.6.0
```

This will create a folder `firebase_core`.

If that doesn't work, then try watching a tutorial on youtube